# Change the font of tabPanels names in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have the shiny app below in which I have tabpanels which are based on a `selectInput()`. Is there a way to change the font and the font color of the tabPanels names ?

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for random distribution app ----
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Tabsets"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("sec","Page",choices=c("Introduction","Explore Funds"),selected = "Introduction"),





    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("tabers"),



    )
  )
)

# Define server logic for random distribution app ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$tabers<-renderUI({
    if(input$sec=="Introduction"){
      tabsetPanel(id="I",type="tabs",tabPanel("Introduction", id = "StartHR"))
    }
    else{
      tabsetPanel(id="I2",type="tabs",tabPanel("Explore Funds", id = "StartHR2"))

    }
                                              })


}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this CSS:

```
.nav-tabs>li>a {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans", sans-serif;
  color: red;
}
```

You have to put it in a `tags$style`:

```
css <- '.nav-tabs>li>a {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans", sans-serif;
  color: red;
}'

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML(css))),
  ......
```

Comment: it works  but why "Lucida Sans", sans-serif ? Which of the 2 is the font? I want to use "Roboto".( I have already  downloaded it)

Comment: @firmo23 The first font is taken if it is found, otherwise the second font is taken.